# How to toggle multiple li elements with a click event from the "a" tag within clicked list item

Tags: jquery, html

I wanna toggle the `checkedList` and `selectedList` classes on all the list items with the class `privListItem` when an event is received from its `a` tag element and finally place the text within the respective span with class `privLabel` element into the div with class `privLabel_textHere`.

```
    <div class="privLabel_textHere"></div>

    <div class="psSelectDD dn">
      <ul class="psSelectUl">
         <li class="privListItem checkedList selectedList">
           <a href="/pp" class="psLink">
             <span class="privLabel">PP</span>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li class="privListItem">
           <a href="/pf" class="psLink">
             <span class="privLabel">PF</span>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li class="privListItem">
           <a href="/po" class="psLink">
             <span class="privLabel">PO</span>
           </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS below

```
    $(".psSelectDD li").find("a").on("click", function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: What you want can easily be done with a little research. Look up .toggleClass() and .text()

Comment: If you invest half an hour of your time reading the [summary of jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/) (and selectors) it'll save you a lot of time in the future. Then spend another hour or two clicking in for more detail on methods that you think you might use regularly...

Comment: I think as a newbie, I should actually do what you have said. Thank you for the advice @nnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".psSelectDD li a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".privListItem").toggleClass("checkedList selectedList");
   var text = $(this).find(".privLabel").html();
   $(".privLabel_textHere").html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After following @nnnnnn advice, I have finally gotten the answer to my own question. Hahah... weird, right??

```
    $(".psSelectDD li").find("a").on("click", function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".privListItem").removeClass("checkedList selectedList");

            $this.parent("li").toggleClass('selectedList checkedList');
    });
```